# Incluir directorios en Deploy Unit de genexus

Tags: genexus

Tengo una webapp en donde agregué algunos directorios dentro de static.
Hay alguna forma de incluir esos directorios en el war que se genera con Deploy Unit?

Lo único que conseguí es hacer un zip y agregar el zip al deploy, pero al momento de desplegar la aplicación me queda el archivo .zip dentro de static, sin que se descomprima.

Gx16 + java + Tomcat 8

Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los archivos y directorios a incluir en el WAR File se manejan en un archivo que deberías de tener en el directorio web de tu modelo, con el nombre DeploymentUnit1_user.gxdproj (el nombre cambia si cambias el nombre del deployment).

Si asumimos que tu directorio a incluir es NuevoDirectorio dentro de static, entonces deberías agregar o modificar:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AdditionalDirectory>static\NuevoDirectorio</AdditionalDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

En el caso de que quieras agregar jars por ejemplo que estén en el directorio lib de tu modelo, deberías de incluir algo similar a esto:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AdditionalFileDestination></AdditionalFileDestination>
</PropertyGroup>
<AdditionalFile Include="lib\GeneXusCryptography-17.2.0.jar">
    <RelativeTargetDir>WEB-INF/lib</RelativeTargetDir>
</AdditionalFile>
<AdditionalFile Include="lib\SecurityAPICommons-17.2.0.jar">
    <RelativeTargetDir>WEB-INF/lib</RelativeTargetDir>
</AdditionalFile>
```

En este artículo de la wiki se explica como [customizar el gxdproj](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?45672,Customize%20GeneXus%20Deployment%20capabilities).

Y en este hay un [ejemplo](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?36315,Sample%20content%20of%20DeploymentUnit_user.gxdproj%20File).

Comment: Espectacular Pablo. Quedó perfecto. Mil gracias.