# Como Incluir directorios y archivos en deploy unit

Tags: genexus

Tengo que incluir un xlsx como template en el archivo war del deploy unit y no se como lograrlo. Quería seguir los pasos de este link :[Incluir directorios en Deploy Unit de genexus](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/497832/incluir-directorios-en-deploy-unit-de-genexus/600478#600478)
pero sólo dice como modificar el archivo deployment1_user.gxdproj.
He visto que se puede utilizar el msbuild para crear un war a partir de ese archivo. El tema es que yo creo el war de otra manera, con un .bat y adentro teniendo el comando jar -cf. Cómo se podría incluir un archivo de esta última manera, es decir ejecutando un archivo .bat.

[image: Realizo deploy]

[image: Carpetas creadas del deploy]

Cuando hago el deploy me crea esta carpeta. Luego ejecuto el .bat
con el comando jar -cf nombre_del_archivo.war. para guardar todo lo que está adentro de esa carpeta de la imagen.
Ahora lo que hice es entrar a la carpeta "static" y agregar una carpeta nueva "templateXLS" y adentro el archivo xlsx. Luego ejecuté el .bat para que empaquete el war junto con esa nueva carpeta. Quería saber si es posible hacerlo así y como desde genexus puedo apuntar a ese directorio desde un procedure.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo armas el war comprimiendo la webapp?  Yo le agregaría al bat algo como  jar -uf nombre_archivo_existente.jar archivo.xlsx.

Comment: puse algunos comentarios e imágenes de ayuda para que se comprenda mejor. Gracias!